# ペイパルの定期支払いでエラーがあった場合、即座に一時停止（Suspended）にする方法

Tags: paypal

定期支払いで決済が失敗した場合、通常次回も定期支払いが行われますが、1回目の失敗でステータスを「一時停止（Suspended）」 にしたいです。

CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileのパラメータ[MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS]に「0」を設定すれば、
1回目の決済失敗で状態が自動的に 「Suspended」 に変更されるのでしょうか？

また、「Suspended」 に変更されるタイミングは決済が失敗したときにリアルタイムに変更されますか？

Answer (score 1):

MAXFAILEDPAYMENTSはデフォルトで0で、これは定期支払いがエラーとなってもsuspendedにならない設定です。

１回失敗するとsuspendedにしたい場合は、この値を1にします。
このステータスになるのはリアルタイムに変更されます。

注意していただきたいのは、
インターバルが週や半月、月の場合は５日ごとに最大２回まで（初回をいれて計３回）自動リトライされます。
このリトライについてはやめる設定がないので、インターバルが日以外の定期支払いでは
最大３回まで決済が試みられます。

MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS=１の時はこの３回まで、
2の場合は、3x2＝6回まで（ただし後半３回は次回定期決済のタイミング）決済が試みられることになります。